# Prop that is an object does not change in value but causes component re-render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a child component that receives an object of data (`myData`)

Via a `console.log` in componentDidUpdate I can see the child component is re-rendering due to `myData` even though the values of the object are still the same.

```
myData changed from 
(5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}] to 
(5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
```

My googling seems to always end up with stuff relating to immuatableJS/redux, but we're not using redux for our project.

It also feels gross using a `JSON.stringify()` check within `shouldComponentUpdate`, like:

```
return JSON.stringify(prevProps.myData) !== JSON.stringify(this.props.myData);
```

Not sure how to make the component more performant without redux. Thoughts?

```
// Parent component
myData={this.getSubCategoryList(dataFromPHP)}

// Child (1) component
{myData.length > 0 && (
  <ChildOne
    myData={myData}
  />
)}

// Child (2) component
<ChildThree
  myData={myData}
/>

// Child (3) component (within render())
myData.map(thing => <Thing>...</Thing>)
```

Comment: make sure that you're not changing the reference of `myData` when it does not change. can you share the code that passes `myData` to your component?

Comment: You can try to change the component to PureComponent

Comment: @FuzzyTree edited to add some abstracted code for how it roughly looks. As far as I can tell we're getting the data from PHP, massaging it in `getSubCategoryList()` and just passing it down through components until we map over it in the final child component.

Comment: Use the `shouldComponentUpdate()` method

Comment: @Andresson all of these components are PureComponents.

Comment: Doesn't seem right for comparing objects @quirimmo

Comment: somehow, your `myData` gets changed. Maybe in your first component, or some child where you pass it through. And that's hard to debug if you don't show what the components do and the flow of the application. 
So what you could try, that's what I meant with my comment, it is to limit the updates of components checking inside `componentShouldUpdate` method of components that the `myData` really changed values. In this case, return true so it gets really updated.

Comment: where does `myData` originally come from?